# @JsonProperty not mapping the value to POJO

Tags: java, json

I have a string field with keyname as **partNumber_ntk** in my json response structure. I have a string attribute in my POJO for mapping this value which is defined as

```
@JsonProperty("partNumber_ntk")
private String partNumberNtk;
```

The issue is that the json value is not getting mapped to the attribute defined in the POJO. I have tried creating a Custom Json Deserializer as well as tried using the SNAKE CASE naming strategy annotation in my POJO class. But none of these approaches worked. Can someone please suggest what else can be tried and also why the @JsonProperty is not working in this particular scenario.

The reason that I feel that @JsonProperty is not working because the json key has a uppercase letter before the underscore section, which probably is not mapping with the default SNAKE CASE naming strategy.

Comment: you should make constructor with `@JsonCreator` and mark constructor's parameter with `@JsonProperty`

Comment: I am not trying to create a json. I have a json response already present from which I want to read this particular attribute and then map it to the property that I have defined in the POJO.

Comment: yes @sasha. i'm asking you to create `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor for POJO to create object from json.

Answer (score 0):

try to put annotation on the accessor method(getter) of related attribute like

```
 @JsonProperty("label")
 public String getName() { return name; }
```

Comment: This approach did not work